# Delete App from the fan page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How can I delete/uninstall the app from the facebook fanpage using php or javascript Sdk

```
   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'APP_Id',
  'secret' => 'secret_key',
 ));    
 $page_info = $facebook->api("/".$fbPageId."?fields=access_token");

  if( !empty($page_info['access_token']) ) {
        $args = array(
            'access_token'  => $page_info['access_token']
        );
        $pageAccessToken = $page_info['access_token'];
           }
```

In above code $page_info gives the id rather than access token

Comment: You will only get the page access token if you make that request with a user access token with `manage_pages` permission.

Comment: I am not getting the access token instead it given me the facebook page id this is my output :-Array ( [id] => facebookPageId)

Comment: As I said, without `manage_pages` you will get only the page id with that API call.

Comment: we can mange scope when user gets loggedin... and I have already added that on another page.. is it compulsory that i have to again do the same thing??

Comment: heyy I have checked I am getting the access token of the page.. but what if user logged in from facebok and not from out site??

Comment: It doesn't matter where from a user logs in - if he has granted `manage_pages`, you can get the page access token in the above way by using his user access token.